# Postgres deadlock with read_commited isolation

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

We have noticed a rare occurrence of a deadlock on a Postgresql 9.2 server on the following situation:

T1 starts the batch operation:

```
UPDATE BB bb SET status = 'PROCESSING', chunk_id = 0 WHERE bb.status ='PENDING' 
AND bb.bulk_id = 1 AND bb.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM BB WHERE bulk_id = 1 
AND chunk_id IS NULL AND status ='PENDING' LIMIT 2000)
```

When T1 commits after a few hundred milliseconds or so (BB has many millions of rows), multiple threads begin new Transactions (one transaction per thread) that read items from BB, do some processing and update them in batches of 50 or so with the queries:

For select:

```
SELECT *, RANK() as rno OVER(ORDER BY user_id) FROM BB WHERE status = 'PROCESSING' AND bulk_id = 1 and rno = $1
```

And Update:

```
UPDATE BB set datetime=$1, status='DONE', message_id=$2 WHERE bulk_id=1 AND user_id=$3
```

(user_id, bulk_id have a UNIQUE constraint).

Due to an external to the situation problem, another transaction T2 executes the same query with T1 almost immediately after T1 has committed (the initial batch operation where items are marked as 'PROCESSING').

```
UPDATE BB bb SET status = 'PROCESSING', chunk_id = 0 WHERE bb.status ='PENDING' 
AND bb.bulk_id = 1 AND bb.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM BB WHERE bulk_id = 1 
AND chunk_id IS NULL AND status ='PENDING' LIMIT 2000)
```

However although these items are marked as 'PROCESSING' this query deadlocks with some of the updates (which are done in batches as i said) off the worker threads. To my understanding this should not happen with READ_COMMITTED isolation level (default) that we use. I am sure that T1 has committed because the worker threads execute after it has done so.

edit: One thing i should clear up is that T2 starts after T1 but before it commits. However due to a write_exclusive tuple lock that we acquire with a `SELECT for UPDATE` on the same row (that is not affected by any of the above queries), it waits for T1 to commit before it runs the batch update query.

Answer (score 0):

> When T1 commits after a few hundred milliseconds or so (BB has many millions of rows), multiple threads begin new Transactions (one transaction per thread) that read items from BB, do some processing and update them in batches of 50 or so with the queries:

This strikes me as a concurrency problem.  I think you are far better off to have one transaction read the rows and hand them off to worker processes, and then update them in batches, when they come back.   Your fundamental problem is going to be that these rows are effectively working on uncertain state, holding the rows during transactions, and the like.  You have to handle rollbacks and so forth separately, and consequently the locking is a real problem.

Now, if that solution is not possible, I would have a separate locking table.  In this case, each thread spins up separately, locks the locking table, claims a bunch of rows, inserts records into the locking table, and commits.  In this way each one thread has claimed records.  Then they can work on their record sets, update them, etc.  You may want to have a process which periodically clears out stale locks.

In essence your problem is that rows go from state A -> processing -> state B and may be rolled back.  Since the other threads have no way of knowing what rows are processing and by which threads, you can't safely allocate records.  One option is to change the model to:

state A -> claimed state -> processing -> state B.  However you have to have some way of ensuring that rows are effectively allocated and that the threads know which rows have been allocated to eachother.